# FusionChart in JavaScript: How to access .json file by Java Script by webserver (local access not working)

Tags: javascript, json, fusioncharts

Since local access of file (.json files) is not possible by JavaScript.
Are there any web servers that allow loading of the json files in them and so that we could that webserver link as the path in FusionCharts to create Chart.

I used the following code for local access of .json files (by JavaScript) which obviously did not work and looking to replace that webserver link  in the local json file access path (myChart.setJSONUrl("C:/2017/JS/Data/user_count_Copy.json");) with web server link.

```
<html>
<head>        
<title>My First chart using FusionCharts XT - JSON data URL</title>         
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/2017/JS/Data/fusioncharts.js"></script>
</head>   
<body>     
<div id="chartContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>          
<script type="text/javascript"><!--         

  var myChart = new FusionCharts( "column2d", 
               "myChartId", "400", "300", "0" );
  myChart.setJSONUrl("C:/2017/JS/Data/user_count_Copy.json");
  myChart.render("chartContainer");

 // -->     
 </script>      
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Please help if you have any suggestions to access .json files by javascript, which would act as data for FusionCharts 
P.S I can not declare them as arrays and then create charts, will need to work around files only

Comment: Simply install IIS (it takes less time than it took you to write down this question) and then move on to more interesting problems.

Comment: @Tomalak  I haven't used IIS or any webserver earlier and hence my questions: So IIS helps access .json files via javascript as well ? Also, I now need to explore or download - IIS or that version of IIS that specifically works with javascript ?

Comment: Search for "how to install IIS on Windows". I'm not going to write a how-to for you.